# Boost w/ C++ - Curious mutex behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread, boost-mutex

I'm experimenting with `Boost` threads, as it's to my knowledge I can write a multi-threaded `Boost` application and compile it in Windows or Linux, while `pthreads`, which I'm more familiar with, is strictly for use on *NIX systems.

I have the following sample application, [which is borrowed from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882809/boost-mutex-scoped-lock):

---

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define NAP_DURATION    (10000UL)   // 10ms

boost::mutex io_mutex;

void count(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(io_mutex);
        std::cout << "Thread ID:" << id << ": " << i << std::endl;
        if (id == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "I'm thread " << id << " and I'm taking a short nap" << std::endl;
            usleep(NAP_DURATION);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "I'm thread " << id << ", I drink 100 cups of coffee and don't need a nap" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Thread ID:" << id << ": " << i << std::endl;
        boost::thread::yield();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread thrd1( boost::bind(&count, 1));
    boost::thread thrd2( boost::bind(&count, 2));

    thrd1.join();
    thrd2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I installed Boost on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system via:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

And I compile the above code via:

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -I"$BOOST_INLCUDE" -L"$BOOST_LIB"
```

I've run into what appears to be some interesting inconsistencies. If I set a lengthy `NAP_DURATION`, say 1 second (`1000000`) it seems that only thread `1` ever gets the mutex until it completes its operations, and it's very rare that thread `2` ever gets the lock until thread `1` is done, even when I set the `NAP_DURATION` to be just a few milliseconds.

When I've written similar such applications using `pthreads`, the lock would typically alternate more or less randomly between threads, since another thread would already be blocked on the mutex.

---

## So, to the question(s):

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Is there a way to control this behavior, such as making scoped locks behave like locking operations are queued?
3. If the answer to (2) is "no", is it possible to achieve something similar with `Boost` condition variables and not having to worry about lock/unlock calls failing?
4. Are `scoped_lock`s guaranteed to unlock? I'm using the RAII approach rather than manually locking/unlocking because apparently the unlock operation can fail and throw an exception, and I'm trying to make this code solid.

Thank you.

## Clarifications

I'm aware that putting the calling thread to sleep won't unlock the mutex, since it's still in scope, but the expected scheduling was along the lines of:

- Thread1 locks, gets the mutex.
- Thread2 locks, blocks.
- Thread1 executes, releases the lock, and immediately attempts to lock again.
- Thread2 was already waiting on the lock, gets it before thread1.

Comment: Just a guess, but doesn't `usleep` put the parent process to sleep? Maybe try using `boost::this_thread::sleep`. Strange to have a sleeping thread hold a lock.

Comment: @JohnnyCage It is a common misconception. `usleep` stops only calling *thread*. See discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915292/do-sleep-functions-sleep-all-threads-or-just-the-one-who-call-it). However it's true that `this_thread::sleep` is preferable

Comment: Oh, I know that `sleep` just suspends the calling thread, and doesn't release the lock. I'm more concerned about the scheduling. I would have expected that thread 2, since it's already blocking on the lock, would execute before thread 1 since it would have to re-acquire the lock.

Comment: Worth mentioning, that there is an implementation of [pthreads for windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/). Concurrency is standardized since C++11, so you can just use [`std::thread` et al.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) instead of boost. Also worth mentioning that `std::cout` is buffered and not thread safe. It could be an issue. Also, there is no `usleep` on Windows, if portability is a concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes and no. You shouldn't have any expectations about which thread will get a mutex, since it's unspecified. But it's certainly within the range of expected behavior.

> Is there a way to control this behavior, such as making scoped locks behave like locking operations are queued?

Don't use mutexes this way. Just don't. Use mutexes only such that they're held for very short periods of time relative to other things a thread is doing.

> If the answer to (2) is "no", is it possible to achieve something similar with Boost condition variables and not having to worry about lock/unlock calls failing?

Sure. Code what you want.

> Are scoped_locks guaranteed to unlock? I'm using the RAII approach rather than manually locking/unlocking because apparently the unlock operation can fail and throw an exception, and I'm trying to make this code solid.

It's not clear what it is you're worried about, but the RAII approach is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you surprised, exactly ?
If you were expecting thread 2 to acquire the mutex while thread 1 is asleep, then, yes, this is expecting behaviour and your understanding was wrong, because your lock is in scope.

But if you are surprised because of lack of alternance between thread 1 and thread 2 at the end of loop iteration, then you can have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847995/why-does-stdcondition-variable-make-scheduling-unfair) about scheduling that seems "unfair"

Comment: The latter part about "unfair scheduling" was what I was looking for. Thanks!